# Young adult science fiction book series about a teen boy with two scientist parents who tell him to run one day when people show up

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

Looking for a young adult book series I read as a kid, around 2013/2014.

From what I can remember, the protagonist is a teen boy. He lives with two scientist parents and they move a lot. He comes home and they tell him they need to leave suddenly. People show up and they tell him to run. I vaguely remember there being small spherical drones. This part is vague and may not be 100% real, but I somewhat remember that he comes back and his parents have been replaced by robots or something, so he runs away again.

I believe this was an ongoing series. I think there were at least 2, maybe 3 books in the series at the point that I read it, but I could be mistaken.

Other little plot points I remember;

- A school he was taken to with other kids, maybe genetically modified.
- Visiting someone in a manor where there was a telescope, and then I think sneaking back into that manor using a canoe

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year/s did you read these books and when do you think they might've been published? Also, do you recall how many books there were in the series?

Comment: I think it was 2013/2014 that i read them and i believe it was an ongoing series at that point but i was 13 at the time so no solid memory. I think there was at least 2, maybe 3. Other little plot points i remember is a school he was taken to with other kids, maybe genetically modified. Visiting someone in a manor where there was a telescope, and then i think sneaking back into that manor using a canoe.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Thinking that your parents have been replaced by aliens/robots/whatevers is surprisingly common in real life; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capgras_delusion